# Selenium Webdriver 2.47.0 throws invocation exception with FF28

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, webdriver, xpi

I am using VS2015 EE (Version 14.0.25431.01 with Update 3) on Win 7
and Firefox v.28 browser not invoking from Selenium Webdriver version 2.47

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkUcB.png)

On this line, I' ve the following exception:

The process can not access the file:

'D:\Users(userprofile)\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous.511c4407b3df427791b4f7e1771eb39a.webdriver-profile.staging\webdriver.xpi\platform\WINNT_x86-msvc\components\webdriver-firefox-esr-previous.dll'

Please help me to avoid this error.

Answer (score 0):

So please check the network settings firewalls, proxies. Update of antivirus software or security platform created for cyber-battlefield.

I've resolved killing such a process.